# iptables optimization - state NEW?

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a set of rules that implement VIP behavior - all in the nat table.  Obviously I want to do as little processing as possible to packets.

It's not clear to me whether "-m state --state NEW" is actually an optimization in this case or not.  Will that give packets on an established connection a "fast path" ?

Are there other things I can do to optimize a series of IP:port comparisons and "-j DNAT" rules?

EDIT:  Example tables

```
-t nat -A OUTPUT -j VIPS

-t nat -A VIPS -d 10.0.154.213/32 -p tcp -m tcp -dport 80 -j SVC-FOO
-t nat -A VIPS -d 10.0.140.123/32 -p tcp -m tcp -dport 80 -j SVC-BAR
-t nat -A VIPS -d 10.0.221.241/32 -p tcp -m tcp -dport 80 -j SVC-QUX
# ... could be hundreds of these

# each SVC-* looks something like this
-t nat -A SVC-FOO -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.5000000000 -j EP-FOO-1
-t nat -A SVC-FOO -j EP-FOO-2

# each EP-*-* looks something like this
-t nat -A EP-FOO-2 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.244.2.7:9376
```

It's a little more complicated in that there are a few ways that you can end up on a SVC-FOO chain and the EP-* chains may have LOG or MARK rules.

My question is whether looking for state NEW in the VIPs chain helps at all?  Or other optimizations to make?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what your entire table looks like, it's hard to say for sure, but certainly a rule that matches `NEW` packets and sends them off to another chain will speed up handling of packets that are part of a known established connection.

In general, to hit the minimum number of iptables rules with a series of exclusive matches involves constructing a "tree" of the address lookups -- if you've got, say, a /24 of IPv4 addresses to match against, you might build an 8-level tree which looks like this:

```
iptables -t nat -N slash24
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.0.2.0/24 -j slash24
iptables -t nat -N slash25_0
iptables -t nat -N slash25_128
iptables -I slash24 -d 192.0.2.0/25 -j slash25_0
iptables -I slash24 -d 192.0.2.128/25 -j slash25_128
iptables -t nat -N slash26_0
iptables -t nat -N slash26_64
iptables -t nat -N slash26_128
iptables -t nat -N slash26_192
iptables -I slash25_0 -d 192.0.2.0/26 -j slash26_0
iptables -I slash25_0 -d 192.0.2.64/26 -j slash26_64
iptables -I slash25_128 -d 192.0.2.128/26 -j slash26_128
iptables -I slash25_128 -d 192.0.2.192/26 -j slash26_192
[etc etc etc]
```

This isn't something you'd want to do by hand, but if you've got a large number of rules you're (hopefully) managing this programmatically, so you can just script something to create that whole ungodly monstrosity.

Once you've got rules that are down to the /32 matching level, you put all the rules for that host into one chain -- you can't play the same sort of "subnet matching" games on ports, unfortunately.  Hopefully you're not trying to send connections to 60,000-odd different machines based on which port it came in on.

Comment: I edited the question with an example